# Об информационном стиле

Tags: стилистика

Вы что-нибудь слышали об этом стиле? А вот у меня есть книга: **Ильяхов Максим.  Информационный стиль и редактура текста, 2016.**  Мне ее дала почитать одна знакомая, которая работает редактором в журнале. И представьте, они по этой книге сдают экзамен на профпригодность.

Я ее только начала читать, но сразу решила, что для художественного стиля этот метод мало подходит.  **Он прежде всего направлен против канцеляризмов всякого вида и учит говорить максимально просто и информативно, что очень важно в наше перегруженное информацией время.** Это Лев Толстой мог разместить одно предложение на полстраницы, нам же рекомендуют использовать в своих записях язык краткий, точный и лаконичный (если можно вычеркнуть слово, обязательно его вычеркивайте).

Об этой книге я вспомнила, когда читал **комментарий одного из наших у участников:**

"...активность относится к отвлечённым существительным, а они не допускают представления о количестве и счете качеств, свойств и процессов, которые они называют. В контексте о последнем заданном вопросе в ряду других «активность» подвергают трансформации. Вопрос: зачем?"

**Написано красиво, но непонятно.** Я очень долго вчитывалась в текст, но он существовал сам по себе, казался мне предельно закрытым и не расположенным к дискуссии.

**И вопросы:** Что вы думаете об инфостиле, если слышали о нем? Актуален ли он для участников нашего форума?

**Примечание.** Интересно то, что у инфостиля две задачи: убрать из текста всё лишнее и дополнить его пропущенной, но необходимой информацией.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Методы информационного стиля применимы  для текстов-информаций - для новостей, статей, сайтов, инструкций, писем и коммерческих предложений, текстовой рекламы. Основное требование - информативность: меньше слов, больше смысла. Текст в информативном стиле должен быть лаконичным,точным,однозначным, объективным.

Основная задача газетно-информационного стиля заключается в сообщении определенных сведений с определенных позиций с целью достижения желаемого воздействия на читателя.

Информационный стиль не подходит для художественных произведений, стихов, прозы и в целом для эмоционального повествования.

Мне пришлось осваивать его, когда пришла в газету, уже на пенсии. Поначалу писала очерки о ветеранах, там было всё в порядке, с публицистикой знакома давно. Но вот меня попросили написать информацию о городском мероприятии, и я поняла, что не умею писать информации - лишние эмоции, украшательства, сложные предложения. У нас опытный редактор, научил, как повысить информативность:

Убрать

1. фразы с отглагольными существительными, канцеляризмы;
2. повторы;
3. красочные определения и обстоятельства;
4. клише, разговорные междометия, лишние союзы и ничего не значащие фразы(мусорные);
5. модальность (должно, можно, нужно, необходимо, не стоит, стоит) и местоимения;
6. лишнюю информацию;

Добавить недостающую информацию и расставить все по местам.

Никаких междометий и восклицаний,никаких обобщенных определений и наречий (абсолютный, безусловный, в целом, всякий, весьма, общий, около, разнообразный),никаких клише,паразитов времени (в настоящий момент, в настоящее время, сейчас, нынче, на сегодняшний день). Как можно меньше причастных оборотов.Сложные предложения — разбить.

Не сразу, но научилась.Особенно трудно было избавиться от оценочности, эмоций, хочется же своё отношение показать, но оказалось, оно никому не нужно, нужна короткая информация, а оценку дадут читатели.Поэтому хронику я не люблю, избегаю.

У нас на сайте форум научный, следовательно, и стиля нужно придерживаться научного, вернее научно-популярного. Ему тоже свойственна информативность, точность, объективность, логика.Но здесь важны и примеры, и ваше отношение тоже иногда требуется, какой смысл следовать информативному стилю? Здесь нужен ясный ответ на вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваше мнение. Лозунг у них такой: лаконично, понятно и интересно доносить сложную информацию. Это даже не стиль, а принцип сильного текста любого жанра и в любой ситуации. Надо писать просто, чтобы текст понимали и хотели прочитать. Парадокс  в том, что писать сложно - довольно легко.

Comment: Это точно, гениальное всё просто,но  это простое создать непросто. Ещё Чехов говорил, что умение писать - это умение вычёркивать. Вот в ГИА сейчас сжатое изложение - первый шаг к постижению информативного стиля. Приёмы сжатия как раз и учат передавать самую важную информацию, отбросив ненужную и всякие украшательства, не добавляющие смысла.

Comment: Людмила, а Вы про этого  Макима Ильяхова что-нибудь слышали? У него есть сервис Главред для улучшения текста https://yandex.ru/search/?lr=213&clid=1955454&win=152&msid=1491591779.84628.22910.4783&text=сервис%20главред  Можно вставить написанный текст и проверить его. Но меня пока результаты не впечатлили.

Comment: Слышала.  Sibylla, это же для копирайтеров и рекламщиков, а для нас  инфотекст будет сух, выжимки, а не текст. Мне это не надо. Учиться есть чему, наша речь действительно заштампована, сплошные стоп-слова и клише. Но ведь время такое. Будем работать над этим, работать над чистотой речи и её качеством.